Нужны ли тире в тех местах, где они стоят? Насколько они обязательны?
На территории функционируют четыре школы, две из них — частные.
Моя комната — единственная в доме, которая мне нравится.

(1) На территории функционируют 4 школы, двЕ из них — // частные.
Факультативное тире и пауза перед сказуемым, выраженным прилагательным. Если ставится  тире, то делается пауза, и ударением будет выделено подлежащее.
При отсутствии тире  паузы нет, а ударение уходит в конец предложения на сказуемое. Авторский выбор.
(2) Моя кОмната — // единственная в доме, / которая мне нрАвится.
Тире ставится, увеличенная пауза делается, а иначе смысл можно понять неверно (моя комната единственная в доме, то есть в доме только одна комната). А она единственная из всех, которая нравится.
